# Excel Data Analysis: creating groups and aggregates

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say I have an Excel worksheet with two columns and five rows like this:

```
Type Value
----------
B    1
A    4
B    2
B    2
A    4
```

How can I get Excel to aggregate the data for me? I want something like this (SUM):

```
Type Sum
--------
A    8
B    5
```

or like this (COUNT):

```
Type Count
----------
A    2
B    3
```

Of course, this is just sample data. The real sheet has a few hundred types, each with dozens to hundreds of entries. I don't want to use a macro. I have access to Excel 2010 and Excel 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Consolidate (Tab Data - Group data Tools)

Reference is your data range

Select use labels in left column

Comment: Got it! I'd been playing with this myself, but never got it to work. I was trying to use the top row for the headers, and was ignoring the value column while working the count first. Using labels from the left column but still counting on the values column and I got what I needed. I also had to sort on the type column first.

Answer (score 2):

Try the SUMIF and COUNTIF functions.

For example:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A5, "=A", B1:B5)
```

or

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A5, "=B", B1:B5)
```

Comment: This means I know what all my types are.  Obviously the sample data is just that: a sample. The real data has a few hundred types, each with dozens of entries. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2):

Check out Pivot Tables! They are by far the greatest feature in Excel - and are just the right tool for your problem:

1. Insert a pivot table (*Insert tab*->*Pivot table*)
2. Use your data as Data source
3. Drag the *Type* field to the *Row Labels*
4. Drag the *Value* field to the *Values*

Your sum is done! If you want the count instead, double click the *Value* field in and select *Count* as the aggregate method. If you want to see both, simply drag the *Value* field in again and change it to *Count*.